# Spring Boot Kafka: Consume same message with all instances for specific topic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a spring boot application (let's say it's called app-1) that is connected to a kafka cluster and that consumes from a specific topic, let's say the topic is called "foo". Topic foo always receives a message when another application (let's say it's called app-2) has imported a new foo-item into the database. 
The topic is primarily meant to be used in a third application (let's say it's called app-3) which sends out some e-Mail notification to people that may be interested in this new foo-item. App-3 is clustered, meaning there are multiple instances of it running at the same time. Kafka automatically balances the foo-topic messages between all these instances because they use the same consumer-id. This is good and in the case of app-3 it is actually desired.

In the case of app-2, however, the messages from the foo-topic are used for cache eviction. The logic is, basically, that if there is a new foo-item then the currently existing caches should probably be cleared, because their content depends on the foo-items. The issue is that app-2 is also clustered, which means that by default kafka-logic, every instance will only receive some of the messages sent to the foo-topic. This does not work correctly for this specific app tho, because whenever there is a new foo-item, all of the instances need to know about it because all of them need their clear their local caches.

From what I understand I have these two options if I want to keep the current logic:

- Introduce a distributed cache for all instances of app-2 so that they all share the same cache. Then it does not matter if only one instance receives a foo-item, because the cache eviction will also affect the cache of the other instances; even though they never learned about the foo-item. I would like to avoid this solution, as a distributed cache would add a noticeable amount of complexity and also overhead.
- Somehow manage to use a different consumer-id for each instance of app-2. Then they would be considered different consumers by kafka and they all would get each foo-topic message. However, I don't even know how to programmatically do this. The code of the application is not aware of replicated instances, there is no way to access any information about what node it is. If I use a randomly generated string on startup, then each time such instance restarts it would be considered a new consumer and would have to re-process all previous messages. That would be incorrect behavior as well.

Here is my bottom line question: Is it possible to make all instances of app-2 receive all messages from the foo-topic without completely breaking the way kafka is supposed to work? I know that it is probably very unconventional to use kafka-messages for cache eviction and I am entirely able to find an alternative mechanism for the cache eviction logic that does not depend on kafka-topic messages. However, the applications are for demonstration purposes and I thought it would be cool if more than one app read from this topic. But if I end up having to hack a dirty workaround to make it work then it's also bad for demonstration purposes and I would rather implement an alternative way of cache eviction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could use different consumer ids with random strings.

If notifications are being read from the beginning, then you probably have `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` set to `"earliest"` somewhere in your consumer configuration. If this is the case, removing it will probably solve your problems - when the app will start it will only receive notification sent after the consumer started listening.

Comment: This actually sounds like a really good idea for this particular use-case. Since the messages are only used for cache-busting it does not matter if app-2 misses messages that were sent while the instance was not running. I will try this out and see if it works as you described. If so then this answers my question and I will accept your answer!